# tflearn error: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice'. How should I change to correct rank?

Tags: python, tensorflow, rank, tensor, tflearn

I am attempting to make a CRNN (Convolutional Recurrent Neural Network), using tflearn, which inputs 17 grayscale images of 28 by 28.

The network is:

```
def rnn_conv_lstm_model(width, height, sequence_length):
   network = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, sequence_length, height, width, 1])
   network = tflearn.reshape(network, [-1, height, width, 1])
   network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
   network = tflearn.max_pool_2d(network, 2)
   network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
   network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
   network = tflearn.max_pool_2d(network, 2)
   network = tflearn.reshape(network, [-1, sequence_length, int((height/2**2)*(width/2**2)*64)])
   network = tflearn.lstm(network, 256)
   network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 2, activation='sigmoid')
   network = tflearn.regression(network, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', learning_rate=0.001, name="output1")
   return network
```

This model is then fed into:

```
get_input_data()
# train the model
model = tflearn.DNN(rnn_conv_lstm_model(28, 28, 17), tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(X_input_data, Y_labels, show_metric=True, batch_size=None, snapshot_step=None, n_epoch=1)
```

The 2 errors I get are "Exception in thread Thread-8" and are as follows:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [1,2], [1,17], [1,17], [1].
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [1,2], [1,17], [1,17], [1].
```

From looking around and researching, I'm fairly sure that rank means number of dimensions. As a result, as each input shape in the error above starts with a 1, I would assume that it should be possible to reshape these to a shape of rank 1 relatively easily. Having said this, I'm not sure how to, and even not sure if this idea is correct at all.

I have looked at the shape of my X_inputs and Y_label before they are fed into the network, and they are as follows:

```
X_inputs shape:
(17, 1)
X_inputs:
[[<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_35:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_26:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_30:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_27:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_31:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_28:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_29:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_34:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_36:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze_37:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]
 [<tf.Tensor 'Squeeze:0' shape=(28, 28, 1) dtype=int32>]]


Y_label shape:
(1, 2)
Y_label:
Tensor("one_hot_2:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32)
```

The data is obtained through this function:

```
def get_input_data():
   global X_input_data
   X_input_data = generate_images()
   X_input_data = np.array(X_input_data)
   X_input_data = X_input_data.reshape(17, 1)
   #X_input_data = X_input_data.reshape(-1, 17, 1)  -- if using this, error declares input shapes to be [1,2], [1,1], [1,1], [1]

   global Y_labels
   Y_labels = y
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and now need to complete the CRNN quite soon. I would like it to run on more epochs than 1 of course, but I am just trying to get it to run at all at the moment.

If someone could help me with resolving this, that would be very much appreciated. If you would like some more information/code then I'm sure I could provide it.